# how to track x and y coordinates in onTouch event?

Tags: android, android-layout

As finger moves on screen i want to track continuously x and y coordinates on **MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE** Event.

> meanwhile i should be able to know whether x,y values are increasing or decreasing.
>   Is it possible to do this, any help would be appreciated .

Comment: motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY() ? Just create some variables like `lastX`,`lastY` and then compare them with motionEvent.getX() and so on

Comment: @Ekalips i tried this code but unable track                                               initX=e.getX();
          initY=e.getY();
          a=e.getX();
          b=e.getY();
          if(a<initX)
          {
           //decrementing x         }
          else
          {
            //incrementing       Y          }
          if(b<initY)
          {
            //decrementing x           }
          else
          {
            //decrementing y 
          }

Answer (score 0):

You just have to capture the starting coordinates during the `ACTION_DOWN` event and compare them to the the coordinates during `ACTION_MOVE`

Something like:

```
public class MyView extends ViewGroup {

    private float startX;
    private float startY;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startX = event.getX();
                startY = event.getY();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                float dx = startX - event.getX();
                float dy = startY - event.getY();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

If you want to track it even more then you can create a helper class which tracks a sample of the events to give you a direction, etc